# How do you record database response file from oracle 12.1

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to record a database response file from dbca in Oracle 12.1. I know that there is a small checkbox in 12.2 at the "Summary" page in dbca, but it's not there in 12.1. Is the ability just not available in 12.1 or is there another way? I do not want to record a template, just the database response file.

Answer (score 0):

> You can run Oracle Database Configuration Assistant in silent or response file mode to configure and start an Oracle database on your system. To run Oracle Database Configuration Assistant in silent or response file mode, use the `dbca.rsp` response file in the `ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\assistants\netca` directory, and the response directory in the database\response directory on the DVD.

I think you need to modify the `dbca.rsp`to use it in silent mode. Please refer the following documentation for how to do that.

[Running Database Configuration Assistant in Response File Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/advance.htm#NTDBI7454)

As you have asked [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171824/how-to-save-response-file-in-dbca-oracle-12c), saving response file from DBCA is available from Oracle 12.2 only.

Comment: I've read the documentation, and I understand how you can use a response file to create a database, but I don't know how to record a response file so that I can use it again to create the DB the same was as before. I know of the default .rsp as well but how can you record the DB you create?

Comment: Saving response file option is available from 12.2, as you have mentioned.